How can I configure Mongodb schema to delete mongodb record automatically in a collection using TTL property from another collection
I'm using Nestjs with Mongodb and want to delete record automatically from api-hit logs collection after the TTL is expired.  I know how to configure the schema for auto - deletion of records using expiresAfterSeconds but the scenario is:

Each record in the collection will have different TTL.
The TTL property for each record is present in another collection.
The common identifier for e.g. is 'username' property in both collections.

TTL configuration with constant 'expireAfterSeconds'.
Const mongoose = require(‘mongoose’)
Const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
{
createdOn: {
type: Date,
required: true
},
.
.
.
}, {timestamps: true})

**userSchema.index({createdOn: 1}, {expireAfterSeconds: 3600});**

But what I want is to configure 'expireAfterSeconds' dynamically something like below (Each record should have different TTL)
**userSchema.index({createdOn: 1}, {expireAfterSeconds: dynamicTTL});**

Kindly provide me solution for the above dear fellow developers!

Consider refactoring your schema to store the documents in same collection. In MongoDB, documents that are meant to be accessed together should be stored together. Another alternative is that you can set up change stream to trigger the deletion

The TTL index is created at collection level. You cannot set it for each document level (though each document can get affected differently by this index).

TTL index can be the same, please set expiryAfterSeconds to 0 as shown below.
userSchema.index({createdOn: 1}, {expireAfterSeconds: 0});

Then adjust “createdOn” with respect to users while creating api-hit-log documents. While creating access logs, log expiry settings collections must be queried for the current user, and the retention time is to be fetched and used to calculate an adjusted createdOn.
The effect is the documents will be automatically removed from the system upon meeting createdOn with system date.
E.g. Today two log entries have been created for two users - u1 and u2. As per the business need, the retention time for u1 and u2 are 1 day and 2 days respectively. The createdOn key has been adjusted as shown below, therefore the log entries of the users - u1 and u2, will be automatically removed on 25th and 26th respectively.
log expiry time : access time + retention time (in seconds)
log expiry time for user u1 = 24.04.2024 14:00:00 + (60 * 60 * 24 * 1) = 25.04.2024 14:00:00
log expiry time for user u2 = 24.04.2024 16:00:00 + (60 * 60 * 24 * 2) = 26.04.2024 16:00:00

Notes on implementation:

Since timestamps have been turned on, the key createdAt will serve the same original purpose of the key createdOn.
In case timestamps is turning off, the original createdOn can still can be worked out. However, a new separate key instead of createdOn may be an ideal choice under this situation.
Since we are adjusting value of createdOn, it is better to rename this key to a more meaningful name.

This post is based on the similar Q&A.
Expire Documents at a Specific Clock Time
